# Free memory in php for processing large arrays

Tags: php, arrays, memory, memory-management

The following should be run on a large array from a MySQL table:

```
$v1_views = $database->get_all("SELECT image_id FROM image_views");
$v2_array = array();
foreach ($v1_views as $view)
   $v2_array[$view["image_id"]]++;
```

($view is also an array with 2 variables from the table)

I've tried something similar and it gave me an error that the memory was full.
So I'm thinking, would it be a good idea to add this to the end of this foreach()?:

```
unset($view["image_id"]);
```

So it doesn't create yet another large array...
Or perhaps just this after foreach():

```
unset($view);
```

After this I'll also have to insert all of these variables in MySQL with UPDATE on 10000+ rows

Which one would have the safest results? Or is there something better?
And how can I safely do all of this, ensuring that it successfully completes without stuff overloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of space is being used by `$v1_views` and `$v2_array`. But `$view` is a tiny array with just one element, it doesn't take up much space. Each time through the loop, the variable is replaced with the value from the next row of the results, and the value from the previous row is automatically reclaimed.

The way to save memory is to *not* make an array of all the query results. Most database APIs have a method to fetch one row at a time, so the structure of the code should be something like:

```
$result = $database->query("SELECT image_id FROM image_views");
$v2_array = array();
while ($view = $result->fetch()) {
    $v2_array[$view["image_id"]]++;
}
```

I just made up the method names `query` and `fetch` -- if you're using a third-party API, check the documentation for the specific names of these methods. If it's a home-grown class, you may need to add these methods if they don't already exist.

Comment: It's an extension to an open source imageboard. Thanks, I'll go  see if something like that is possible with this software.